# how to use cookie-free domains in magento?

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, css, cookie, html

I analyzed my website on Gtmetrix.com for optimization and the result was this:

> There are 245 components that are not cookie-free:

```
http://mysite.com/media/css/dabf35e7cd79eb387a68eed1d5f3f925.css
http://mysite.com/media/css/38f74ae13bf9722265996c2842cba8a5.css
http://mysite.com/media/js/b5de567c1b6b9d971394b4d4887370a1.js
http://mysite.com/skin/frontend/fortis/default/images/logo.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/menu/custom/01.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/menu/custom/02.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/menu/custom/03.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/slideshow/01.jpg
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/slideshow/02.jpg
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/slideshow/03.jpg
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/slideshow/04.jpg
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/slideshow/banner/01.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/slideshow/banner/02.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/slideshow/banner/03.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/icons/large/paintbrush.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/icons/large/responsive.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/icons/large/menu.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/custom/banners/03.png
http://mysite.com/media/wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/custom/banners/11.png
.
.
.
```

> Serve static content from a different domain to avoid unnecessary
>   cookie traffic.

how to solve this?

Comment: Hello. How did you solve that in Magento 2?

Comment: did you get anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Configure another domain for skin and media
2. check that the cookie domain is configured that way, that the cookies are not send along these domains
3. Make sure, that you don't get a problem with the JS due to "same origin policy"

**UPDATE**

1. set the media, skin and js url to your new domain:

   > System > Config > Web > Unsecure/Secure > Base Media URL
   >
   > System > Config > Web > Unsecure/Secure > Base Skin URL
   >
   > System > Config > Web > Unsecure/Secure > Base JavaScript URL
2. Make sure the cookie settings are so, that the cookie is NOT sent to the subdomain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139

   I assume this is the case if you DON'T set the domain - but maybe Magento is change this, so it sets the domain itself. If this is the case, you would either hack magento or use a www. subdomain for your shop.
3. Make sure your JS still works and doesn't throw errors due to Same-Origin-Policy. If this is the case, your JS doesn't work and you see the errors in your browsers console.