# How to use cookie-free domains in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cookie, magento2.2.6

I have recently create gtmetrix report for my site, in that report I found Use cookie-free domains to 0 means nothing. My question is that how to use cookie free domain in magento 2.2.6

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29983/how-to-use-cookie-free-domains-in-magento

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-use-cookie-free-domains

Comment: Thank you @MukeshPrajapati, but 1st is for magento 1 and 2nd is for wordpress, as magento 2 have different settings so both can work for certaing level only.

Comment: Hello @KrunalPathak. Did you found any solution for that?

Comment: hello @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I found following link but I did not get time to implement it, but it seems same as magento 1, I think it might work 

https://belvg.com/blog/cookies-in-magento-2-0.html

Comment: I see this blog. But, can't understand how to configure.

Comment: try to set for entire website first means do as it say like set cookie path / and add domain name as your webiste domain name