# How to use cookie-free domains in magento 2.3.X

Tags: magento2.3.3, cookie, gtmetrix

I have recently create gtmetrix report for my site, in that report I found Use cookie-free domains to 0 means nothing. My question is that how to use cookie free domain in magento 2.3.4

and i see here [same question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/247803/68695) but not any answer

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your main site needs cookies so that the php generated content is on a cookie domain.

Your static content, e.g. images, does not need to be a cookie domain. So create a subdomain static.example.com and configure it to serve images.

Update Base URL for Static View Files and Base URL for User Media Files in admin -> general -> web -> Base URLs.