# Magento 2 Optimization

Tags: magento2, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my website.

On Gtmetrix it is giving me this "warning"
[image]

How can I fix this issue **"Use cookie-free domains"**?

Comment: Please read this [document](https://gtmetrix.com/use-cookie-free-domains.html)

Comment: Please find this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29983/how-to-use-cookie-free-domains-in-magento?rq=1 might be useful for you.

Comment: @RajMohanR Thanks for your reply. I have to add "static.domain.it" in this form? See image ;)  https://ibb.co/BjBf3pX

Comment: Can you please share the configurations made in Cookie Settings https://prnt.sc/n4levo. You will find a configuration Cookie Domain. So you can try using the value ".gyps.it" in it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n4ljor